# Prove that if a set of whole numbers is closed for subtraction, it is closed for addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, binary-operations

The set is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. So far, I only know that for $x, y \in A : (x-y) + y \in A$, But I don't know how to prove that $(x + y)$ is also in $A$ based on this? Any direction would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Hint: $0=x-x$ and $x+y=x-(0-y)$.

Comment: Generally, if $(G,\cdot)$ is a group and $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$ closed under the function $(g,h) \to g\cdot h^{-1}$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the given set. Pick $x \in A$. Then $0=x-x \in A$. For any $a \in A$ we have $-a=0-a \in A$. Hence $a+b=a-(-b) \in A$ for all $a,b \in A$.

Comment: There's a typo: the  last + should be a  –.